# create show/hide javascript from date time

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, frontend, show-hide

**show/hide javascript from date time**
0

I've got some code that I thought should work to show or hide two span depending on the time of day. It currently shows the "closed" span despite the time being later than it is - am I missing anything? The website is running on only two machines so it only needs to get the time set on them.

```html
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>

<br/><br/>
<span id="hours">Hours</span>
<span id="closed">Closed</span> 

<script>

document.ready(function() {

var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();
var time = new Date().getTime();

if (time > start.setHours(8,29) && time < end.setHours(11,32)) {
    document.getElementById("hours").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "none";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("hours").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "block";
    }
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code [works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/7025qkyt/) after resolving two minor errors: "missing ) after argument list" and "document.ready is not a function". It might help to provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It works once you add the required `)` and remove non-JS functions (I.E: `document.ready`)

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript Functions</h2>

<br/><br/>
<span id="hours">Hours</span>
<span id="closed">Closed</span> 

<script>
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();
var time = new Date().getTime();

if (time > start.setHours(8,29) && time < end.setHours(20,32)) {
    document.getElementById("hours").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "none";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("hours").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("closed").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @fauzanrozaq could you upvote and mark as answered? I'm frothing for that 1k rep in SO <3